# Validate email and phone number in the same input with yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have an entry that I am using for 'email' and 'password' and I want to do a check for both.
I am using 'yup'.

****I configured like this:****
*I tried this way but it doesn't work for both.*

```
type forgotPasswordData = {
  email_or_phone: string;
}

var phoneValidation= /^([\s\(\)\-]*\d[\s\(\)\-]*){8}$/
var emailValidation= /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

const forgotPasswordSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email_or_phone: yup.string().matches(phoneValidation, '').matches(emailValidation, '')
});


export default function ForgotPasswordCard() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(forgotPasswordSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email_or_phone: '',
    }
  });

  const handleforgotPassword: SubmitHandler<forgotPasswordData> = async (data) => {
    await new Promise((resolver) => setTimeout(resolver, 2000));
    console.log(data);
  };
```

---

****And I left the 'input' like this:****

```
<Input
  type='text'
  placeholder='Email or mobile number'
  error={errors.email_or_phone}
  {...register("email_or_phone")}
/>
```

Comment: You can use yup's `oneOfSchemas` like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888067/how-to-validate-alternatives-in-yup

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a single RegEx.

Here is that functionality on which you get Success response if you enter correct email or phoneNumber which length should be 10.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [value,setValue]=useState("");
  const onSubmit=()=>{
        var mailFormat = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})|([0-9]{10})+$/;
        if (value == "") {
            alert( "  Please enter your Email or Phone Number  ");
        }
        else if (!mailFormat.test(value)) {
            alert( "EmailAddress/PhoneNumber is not valid. Please provide a valid Email Address or phone number");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert("Success");
        }
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <input placeholder={"TypeHere"} value={value} onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}/>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```